# setAttribute property is not woking in Firefox, for Selenium

Tags: eclipse, selenium, firefox

I am new to Selenium. I am using Eclipse IDE(Version: 2018-09 (4.9.0)) and Firefox(58.0) to run the Selenium test. The browser is loaded and the details are filling up as expected. I want to set a custom attribute value to a control.

In order to set an attribute value to a control, the following code is used:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("document.getElementById('ddlArea').setAttribute('data-muzvalue', '1')");
```

This is working perfectly with Chrome. But in case of Firefox(version:58), it is not working.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got it working with the following

```
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;        
    driver.findElement(By.id("ddlArea")).sendKeys("xxxxxx");
    js.executeScript("document.getElementById('ddlArea').setAttribute('data-muzvalue', '1')");
```